# change displayed time in Eonasdan datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm currently using this [datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), and wanted to use the time picker to allow user to select the durations in HH:MM format. I want that when the HH value is equal to 12 the MM value displayed on the timepicker becomes zero.

for which I am using the following code

```
$("#durationpicker").change(function(){
        var val=$(this).val();
        val=val.slice(0,-3);
        var time = val.split(':');
        //console.log(time+$("#minutespan").text());
        if(time[0]==12){
            console.log('12')
            $("#minutespan").text('00');
                //console.log(time+$("#minutespan").text());
            val=time[0]+':00';
        }
        $(this).val(val);            
    });
```

What i did was add an id = minutespan to the span element containing value of currently displayed minute (line 986 and 1016 of non minified version). The code is successfully changing the value of the span, but it is not reflected in the time picker.

I realize that the code should change the displayed icon, but I'm confused on how to move about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want users to select the `hour` use version 4 and set the `format: 'HH'`.

This will set the `minutes` to `00` and not allow the user to change the `minutes`.

If you are trying to change the date/time of the picker use the [`date(newDate)`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date)  function